# Return all rows if -1 is passed, otherwise rows that match the value

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the below SQL query, where I want to return all rows of the table if -1 is passed as the value for @statusParam. And rows that matches the `@statusParam` value if something passed other than -1.

The status column is a int type column.

```sql
set @statusParam = -1;
SELECT * FROM `db`.table_name where `status` = -1 or `status` = @statusParam;
```

The above query is perfectly working fine for values 1 and 0. Where when 1 is passed from `@statusParam`, the rows that contains status value of 1 are returned. And same for the value 0.

But when I pass -1 value as the value for the @statusParam the SQL query returns empty. Where expected results were to have all rows (that contains 1 and 0 for status column)

Comment: Read your condition carefully: it doesn't match what you say what you want. Currently you're selecting rows where status = -1 or equal to the parameter, which is not the same as all rows if the parameter is -1.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Thanks for pointing out. It lead me to think again. And made the correction to the condition. So the correct condition is " where @statusParam = -1 or `status` = @statusParam " Now it retrieves the correct results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MarkRotteveel, the correct sql query is;

```
set @statusParam = -1;
SELECT * FROM `db`.table_name where @statusParam  = -1 or `status` = @statusParam;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you query isn't working, but this will:

```
SELECT *
FROM db.table_name
WHERE @statusParam in (status, -1)
```

Comment: Their query isn't working because `status = -1` is not the same as `@statusParam = -1`

Answer (score 0):

Add the similar line in your `WHERE` clause

```
IF(@statusParam = -1,true,`status` = @statusParam)
```

It will return the all values if the `@statusParam` equals to -1, if it's not it will use `status` = `@statusParam` condition.